# How to establish a connection between Android and Azure using Python REST API as a Backend?

Tags: android, python, azure, cloud, backend

This question is very detailed so please bear with me.

Recently I have been working on an Android application development.
So, I am trying to develop a back end with Microsoft Azure, so that I can connect to the cloud, use the SQL service offered by the cloud, and obtain feedback from the cloud.

I have been using these approaches:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-python

I am trying to understand the logic behind that connection.

What I did so far is:

1. having the user enter a certain Text from the android app.
2. created a WEB-API using Python on the Azure cloud.
3. created an app service with a SQL database on Azure.

What I want to do:

1. When clicking the "Display" button, passing this text to the cloud.
2. Cloud takes this text and displays it on a website hosted on azure (e.g. 
   myapp.azurewebsites.com)

How can I achieve this approach?

Kindly find below the piece of code that I've been working on:

**JAVA:**

```
package dia.com.sendmessage_azure;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.*;



public class AzureSend extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_azure_send);
    }

    public void clickButton(View view){
        EditText messageEdit = findViewById(R.id.edit);
        String disp=messageEdit.getText().toString();
        TextView show= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vieww);
        show.setText(disp);




    }}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="dia.com.sendmessage_azure.AzureSend">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vieww"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        style="@style/Animation.AppCompat.DropDownUp"
         />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:hint="@string/Edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:onClick="clickButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dia.com.sendmessage_azure">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".AzureSend">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">sendmessage_Azure</string>
    <string name="text">The Message will be displayed here</string>
    <string name="Edit">Enter you text here</string>
    <string name="button">Display</string>
</resources>
```

**Python_Web_API:**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():

  return 'I am a Web APP' #The entered text will be replaced with this one.

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing several pieces here. First, your client app (doesn't really matter whether it's Android, iOS, smart tv, etc.) needs to "hit" an "endpoint" that you create on the backend. This basically means that you need to create a url that can receive information that you're passing from your mobile client. You'll receive the info in your Flask app then open a DB connection and store it there. Your web page (looks like you're going with '/') will pull the necessary info from the database and display it.

You'll need to figure out how your backend should accept the data (should it allow only that one android device? any android device?) and how it should store the data (only have one DB entry and keep overwriting it for every call to the service? new entry for every unique call to the service?)

There are definitely other ways to do it and ways to cheat a bit but I think this is the approach you're going for which is a very typical pattern for a barebones system.

Comment: Thanks a lot @s g , You are right I guess I do have to figure out a way I just wish that there was some kind of sample out there, it would've been much better.